# Обработка исключений при вызове метода класса

Tags: php, исключения

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста по следующему вопросу, PHP 5.6.
Метод с именем $Fname не определен в классе.
Не срабатывает мое исключение при вызове метода класса.
Выводится стандартная ошибка "Fatal error:"

Кусок кода:

```
                        try {

                            $this->Core->ModuleModel->$Fname();

                        }

                        catch (Exception $e) {

                            exit ("Error: " . $e->getMessage());

                        }
```

Comment: fatal error это не исключение, оно даже через set_error_handler не ловится

Comment: В PHP это просто не исключение, используйте method_exists

Comment: Спасибо kroder и Etki . я понял.

Comment: А можно воспользоваться `__call()` и `__callStatic()` и обработать там такие случаи...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если не кидать оттуда кастомный MethodNotExistsException, то лучше не стоит

Comment: @Etki ну да.... я же не предлагаю пустой метод создать)